How to resolve React with Next.js Hydratation Error
hydratation error on Input.tsx and RegisterForm.tsx
This is the Input.tsx code
import { UseFormRegister, FieldValues, FieldErrors } from "react-hook-form";

interface InputProps {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  type?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  required?: boolean;
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
  errors: FieldErrors;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({
  id,
  label,
  type,
  disabled,
  required,
  register,
  errors,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full relative">
      <input
        autoComplete="off"
        id={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        {...register(id, { required })}
        placeholder=""
        type={type}
        className={`
          peer
          w-full
          p-4
          pt-6
          outline-none
          bg-white
          font-light
          border-2
          rounded-md
          transition
          disabled:opacity-70
          disabled:cursor-not-allowed
          ${errors[id] ? "border-rose-400" : "border-slate-300"}
          ${errors[id] ? "focus:border-rose-400" : "focus:border-slate-300"}
        `}
      />
      <label
        htmlFor={id}
        className={`
        absolute
        cursor-text
        text-md
        duration-150
        -translate-y-3
        top-5
        z-10
        origin-0
        left-4
        peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100
        peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0
        peer-focus:scale-75
        peer-focus:-translate-y-4
        transform
          ${errors[id] ? "text-rose-500" : "text-slate-400"}
        `}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;

and this is the RegisterForm.tsx code
'use client'

import { useState} from "react";
import Input from "../components/inputs/Input";
import Heading from "../components/products/Heading";
import {FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm} from 'react-hook-form' 
import Button from "../components/products/Buttons";
import Register from "./page";
import register from "../components/inputs/Input";
import Link from "next/link";
import { AiOutlineGoogle } from "react-icons/ai";


const RegisterForm = () => {


    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

   
    const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues:{
        name: "",
        email:"",
        password: "",
    },
});

    const onSubmit:SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) =>
        {
            setIsLoading(true)
            console.log(data)
        };

    return ( 
    <>
    <Heading title="Sign up for Technify Gadgets"></Heading>
    <Button outline
    label="Sign up with Google"
    icon={AiOutlineGoogle}
    onClick={() => {}}>

    </Button>
    <hr className="bg-slate-300 w-full h-px"/>
    <Input id="name"
    label="Name"
    disabled={isLoading}
    register={register}
    errors={errors}
    required
    />
     <Input id="email"
    label="Email"
    disabled={isLoading}
    register={register}
    errors={errors}
    required
    />
     <Input id="password"
    label="Password"
    disabled={isLoading}
    register={register}
    errors={errors}
    required
    type="password"
    />
    <Button label={isLoading ? "Loading" : "Sign Up"}
    onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}/>
    <p className="text-sm">
        Already have an account? <Link className="underline" href='/login'>
            Log In
        </Link>
    </p>
    </> 
    );
}
 
export default RegisterForm;

Can someone tell me what to do to solve the did not expect server html to contain  in a 
Please, thank you!
I have tried using the useEffect() on what I researched on google and documentation
